# Form tag error:No value > accessor for form control with name

Tags: angular

I have a little problem with part of my form.
This is angular error:

> core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value
>   accessor for form control with name: 'english_group' Error: No value
>   accessor for form control with name: 'english_group'

This is part of this form :

```
<select >
        <option  [(ngModel)]="model.english_group" value="A1" name="english_group">A1</option>
        <option  [(ngModel)]="model.english_group" value="B1" name="english_group">B1</option>
        <option  [(ngModel)]="model.english_group" value="C1" name="english_group">C1</option>
      </select>
```

I want the user to be able to choose a group and this group has been sent in a form, via POST to server, but english_group is send as null how to solve it.

Also part of TypeScript code to help understand what I mean.

```
model: students = {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    surname: '',
    pesel: '',
    phoneNumber:'',
    address:'',
    email:'',
    english_group:'',
    grade:''
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place `ngModel` on `select` not `option`

```
<select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="model.english_group" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    <option value="A1" name="english_group">A1</option>
    <option value="B1" name="english_group">B1</option>
    <option value="C1" name="english_group">C1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried this but then I get:
ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

Comment: Have you add FormsModule in app.module.ts ?

Comment: i edited my answer to include ngModelOptions. see https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#using-a-standalone-ngmodel-within-a-group